# Angular: Random class and id names

Tags: angular

To avoid web scraping, or to make it more difficult, is it in Angular possible to randomize the names of class and id attributes? For example, Instagram employs this strategy, where the class and id attribute names appear to be random strings that are uniquely generated upon every server response.

If Angular does not support this, are there other techniques available to achieve this objective?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't know what you are asking for, but you can generate random ID, Class name and assign in angular templates. Also there is nothing related to angular to genrate readom ID classname

Comment: @PardeepJain the idea behind is to still use the CSS styles applied for those classes / ids. Generating is not a problem. Good question, but I am afraid it is not possible to easily achieve this.

Comment: @smnbbrv it is, and it's pretty easy. It's even easier in Angular.